# How to access to children data in jsreports

Tags: jquery

I'm using http://jsreports.com library to create and design a report using json data. So I want to acces to a children element in my json through myschema.

I have this code

```
 var eee = {
            "dirigeant": [
                {
                    "_id": 8,
                    "_name": "steve",
                    "_txid": 1
                }
            ]
        }
var dataSource = {
            id: "orders",   // Internal reference ID
            name: "Orders",  // Data source name shown to report designer
            data: eee,
            schema: orderSchema
        };
```

and I want to do thing like this

```
 <script>var report = jsreports.createReport('Extrait_RCCM_' + $(".label-warning").text())
            .data('orders') // The report will look for a data source with ID "orders"
            .page(9, 10, 'inches')
            .margins(0.5)
            .header()
             .text('Nom', 0.1, 5.1, 7, 0.5, { fontsize: 11 })
            .text(':  [dirigeant._name] ', 6.5, 0.1, 1, 1)
            .done();
// Render the report
        jsreports.render({
            report_def: report,
            target: $('#textToPrint'),
            showToolbar: false,
            datasets: [dataSource]
        });</script>

<div id="textToPrint"></div>
```

Comment: Provide a working example, otherwise it's really hard to help

Comment: I update my example

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a **working** example. You need to add everything (use jsfiddle to add html/css/js code to demonstrate the problem).

Comment: Normaly my code is too long, but I choose just the code for resolve my problem. But check my update

Comment: Your update has only the javascript code, and I'm not even sure which library you use. a working example (not with all of your code, but a minimal example with minimum code) gives enough information regarding the libs/versions you use and what the problem is...

Comment: library is [jsreports](http://jsreports.com)

Comment: So why not creating a complete [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example that demonstrates your problem?